# Why can't I change document root in apache without error?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, http-status-code-403, documentroot

I'm trying to change my document root in apache so I can start a new project and keep an old one available so I can reference the files. Whenever I try to change the document root, though, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

It seems like I've tried EVERYTHING. In the httpd.conf file, I change the document root line and the line in brackets:

```
DocumentRoot "/Full/Path/To/Root"
<DIRECTORY /Full/Path/To/Root /> I'm not looking at the file right now, but I've changed this part too
```

I'm putting the new root directory in the same location as the default, so those permissions should be OK. I've changed the root directory's permissions to 777 and 744 and it still won't work. I've been spending a lot of time looking for a working solution, but so far, nothing has worked.

In the apache error logs, the message coming up says "Permission denied due to server configuration" (when I get the chance to find the exact message, I'll be sure and post it.)

Any help is very appreciated. I'm running Mac OS Lion with Apache v2 and php 5.5 (if that matters).

Edit:
The error in the error log says
[Mon Jul 22 14:43:38 2013] [error] [client fe80::1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/Webserver/CustomServer/

Comment: File permissions on the target {directory, index file}?

Comment: The directory's permissions right now are drwxr-xr-x but I've had it set so everyone has read, write, and execute access. The index.html file is set to -rw-r--r--

Comment: I just changed the directory's permissions to 707 (like what the default doc root) is and it still is throwing a 403.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after more tinker with the httpd.conf file, I changed the `<DIRECTORY >` tab to say `allow from all` instead of `deny from all`. I'm not looking at the file right now, so I can't remember exactly what the tag says, but I can look it up if anyone else needs to know exactly.